# Find Words in entire module

Tags: ibm-doors

I have skip list contains an ADC, FIFO, DAC, FILO etc.
I want to know whether these words are used in the entire module or not .if used in the module should return the unused words.
I have a program but it is taking too much time to execute.
Please help me with this.

Here is the code :

```
Skip Search_In_Entire_Module(Skip List)    
{   
    int sKey = 0    
    Skip sList      = create()    
    string data = ""
    string  objText1
    Object obj 

    for data in List do 
    {
        int var_count = 0
        for obj in m do 
        {
            objText1 = obj."Object Text"
            if objText1!=null then 
            {
                if (isDeleted obj){continue}
                if (table obj)    {continue}
                if (row obj)      {continue}
                if (cell obj)     {continue}        

                Buffer buf = create()
                buf    =   objText1
                int index = 0
                while(true)
                {
                    index = contains(buf, data, index)
                    if(0 <= index)
                    {
                        index += length(data)
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        var_count++
                        break 
                    }
                }
                delete(buf)
            }
        }
        if (var_count ==0)
        {
            put(sList,sKey,data)
            sKey++
        }
    }
    return sList
}    

Unused_Terminolody_Data = Search_In_Entire_Module(Terminology_Data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering: why is this in a while loop?

```
            while(true)
            {
                index = contains(buf, data, index)
                if(0 <= index)
                {
                    index += length(data)
                }
                else 
                {
                    var_count++
                    break 
                }
            }
```

I would instead just do:

```
index = contains ( buf, data )
if ( index == -1 ) {
     var_count++
}
buf = ""
```

I would also not keep deleting and recreating the buffer. Create the buffer up where you create the object variable, then set it equal to "" to clear it, then delete it at the end of the program.

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Balthos makes good points, and I think there's a little more you could do. My adaptation of your function follows. Points to note:

1. I implemented Balthos's suggestions (above) of taking out the
   'while' loop, and buffer creation/deletion.
2. I changed the function signature. Given that Skip lists are passed
   by reference, and must be created and deleted outside the function
   it's syntactically confusing (to me, anyway) to return them from a
   function. So, I pass both skip lists (terms we're seeking, terms not
   found) in as function parameters. Please excuse me changing variable
   names - it helped me to understand what was going on more quickly.
3. There's no need to put the Object Text in a string - this is
   relatively slow and consumes memory that will not be freed until
   DOORS exits. So, I put the Object Text in a buffer earlier in the
   function, and search that. The 'if (!null bufObjText)' at my line 34
   is equivalent to your 'objText1!=null'. If you prefer, 'if
   (bufObjText != null)' does the same.
4. The conditional 'if (var_count ==0)' is redundant - I moved it's
   functions into an earlier 'if' block (my line 40).
5. I moved the tests for deleted, table, row and cell objects up, so
   that they occur before we take the time to fill a buffer with object
   text - so that's only done if necessary.

Item 2 probably isn't going to have a performance impact, but the others will. The only quesiton is, how large?

Please let us know if this improves the running time over what you currently have. I don't have a sufficiently large set of sample data to make meaningful comparisons with your code.

```
Module modCurrent = current

Skip skUnused_Terminology_Data = create

Skip skSeeking_Terminology_Data = create()

put (skSeeking_Terminology_Data, 0, "SPONG")
put (skSeeking_Terminology_Data, 1, "DoD")


void Search_In_Entire_Module(Skip skTermsSought, skTermsNotFound)
{
    Object obj
    Buffer bufObjText = create()

    int intSkipKey  = 0
    int index       = 0
    string strSkipData = ""

    for strSkipData in skTermsSought do
    {
        int var_count = 0
        bool blFoundTerm = false

        for obj in modCurrent do
        {
            if (isDeleted obj){continue}
            if (table obj)    {continue}
            if (row obj)      {continue}
            if (cell obj)     {continue}

            bufObjText = obj."Object Text"

            if (!null bufObjText) then
            {
                Regexp re = regexp2 strSkipData

                blFoundTerm = search (re, bufObjText, 0)

                if ( blFoundTerm ) {
                    put(skUnused_Terminology_Data, intSkipKey, strSkipData)
                    intSkipKey++
                }
                bufObjText = ""
            }
        }

    delete (bufObjText)
}


Search_In_Entire_Module (skSeeking_Terminology_Data, skUnused_Terminology_Data)

string strNotFound

for strNotFound in skUnused_Terminology_Data do
{
    print strNotFound "\n"
}

delete skUnused_Terminology_Data
delete skSeeking_Terminology_Data
```